# Disjunction of several instances of sigma protocol

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, sigma-protocol

Assume there exists zero-knowledge interactive protocol for a language $L \in NP$ i.e., if an instance $x \in L$ then prover can convince the verifier, that $x \in L$ with high probability without any other information.
A zero-knowledge interactive protocol is said to sigma protocol if it satisfies following conditions

- Three move protocol: In the protocol, prover first sends a message
  $m_1$ to verifier, verifier upon receiving $m_1$ send a $t \in
     \{0,1\}^k$ to prover. Prover based on $t$, compute and send message
  $m_2$ to verifier. Verifier outputs valid ot invalid based on input
  $x$ and the transcript $(m_1,t,m_2)$
- Completeness: If $x \in L$, verifier returns valid
- Special Soundness: For any $x$, if there are two accepting transcript
  $(m_1,t,m_2)$ and $(m_1,t^\prime,m_2^\prime)$ where $t \neq
     t^\prime$, one can extract witness for $x$.
- Zero-*knowledgeness*: There exists a polynomial-time simulator $M$, which on input $x$ and
  a random $t$, outputs an accepting conversation of the form     $(m_1,t,m_2)$, with the same probability distribution as conversations between the honest $(P,V)$ on input $x$

Assume, there exists a sigma protocol for language $L$ and consider $n$ instances $(x_1,x_2,x_3,.....x_n) \in L$.  Consider, prover has $n$ instances of $(x_1,x_2,x_3,.....x_n) \in L$ and witness $w_i$ for only one  $x_i \in L$. Can we construct a sigma protocol to prove that that atleast one $x_i \in L$ out of $n$ instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a truly elegant solution to this problem by Cramer, Damgard and Schoenmakers from [CRYPTO'94](https://www.win.tue.nl/~berry/papers/crypto94.pdf). You can also read about it in Section 4 of the [survey on $\Sigma$ protocols](http://www.cs.au.dk/~ivan/Sigma.pdf) by Damgard.

Comment: If a protocol satisfy zero-knowledge property, does it mean simulator produces accepting transcript?

Comment: This is a by-product. On statements in the language, yes.